# Why am I getting 'ppm: Command not found' on Mac OSX after installng ActiveState Perl?

Tags: macos, perl

I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.5.

When I type Perl -version I get:

```
This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 3 (v5.12.3) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
(with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Then when I type ppm the perl package manager isn't found.

```
ppm: Command not found.
```

Is there something wrong with my installation? How can I fix this issue. I attempted to install the latest version of of ActiveState and unfortunately, it didn't overwrite the current version.

Comment: I think you will have to install `Command Line Tools for XCode` in order to install separate modules. So I guess that OS X comes with perl but not with the package manager.

Comment: You could also try searching for `ppm` in your system to see if it's installed or not using `locate ppm` from your terminal. If you find that `ppm` is installed then perhaps it's not in your path then you can try to execute the command using a full path, also perhaps you'll need to use `sudo`: `sudo /<full_path_to_ppm>/ppm`

Comment: I tried to use the locate command and got this result: WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist. When I use sudo, I cannot enter a password since when the prompt for the password displays, Terminal hangs and I can't enter anything.

Comment: To use the `locate` command you must first create your locale database using `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist`. This won't help you in this case, but the `locate` command is a must have=)

Answer (score 4):

> I attempted to install the latest version of of ActiveState and unfortunately, it didn't overwrite the current version

Don't try to overwrite your system `perl`; that will get you nothing but grief. Make sure you put the path to ActiveState `perl` ahead of system paths in your `.bashrc` or similar configuration file for your shell. See also [OS X Configuration](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.16/install.html#os%20x%20configuration).

Comment: Thanks. I look at at the instructions on ActiveState. I agree this is the way to go. However, I don't know how to change the path using the instructions they provide. I think it gets down to my skill using the Terminal. Can you tell me what to type (exactly). I also don't know how to edit my .bashrc file.

Comment: OK, I don't mean to offend you, but I think you've put the cart before the horse. You should learn how to use the computer and operating system you chose before taking up programming. Otherwise, it is going to be very, very, *very*, **very** frustrating for you.

Comment: Well, sure. But I'm trying to work it out by asking for help. And, I am learning a lot so far.

Answer (score 0):

PPM is used by Activestate Perl which is for windows, if I correct.

Please use cpan, cpanm (or perlbrew) to manage perl packages on mac osx.

http://perlbrew.pl/Perlbrew-and-Friends.html

http://library.linode.com/linux-tools/utilities/cpanm

Regards,

Comment: ActiveState does make a version of perl for OSX, Linux, and some Unix flavors. I haven't used the OSX version, but do believe it comes with PPM.